# Data Filtering in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Thanks for the help in advance. As a part of learning react, I am trying to display a list of items that are entered through the form. I was able to display the items. But I have a year filter. That is I want to display the data that belongs to the corresponding year. Since I'm new to react I was not able to achieve this. When I googled I got the filter concept. But I didn't understand to implement it. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue. The react code is added in the below provided link

https://codesandbox.io/s/expense-tracker-047z67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  filteredData function in the ExpensesList.js file and pass the .map fucntion filteredData instead of props.listDatas
like the below code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
    import ExpenseItem from "./ExpenseItem/ExpenseItem";
    import ExpenseDateFilter from "./ExpenseDateFilter/ExpenseDateFilter";
    import "./ExpenseList.css";
    
    const ExpenseList = (props) => {
      const [currentSelectedyr, setCurrentSelectedyr] = useState("2020");
      const yearSelected = (year) => {
        setCurrentSelectedyr(year);
      };
    
      const filteredData = props.listDatas.filter((item) => {
        return item.date.split("-")[0] === currentSelectedyr;
      });
    
      return (
        <div className="expenses">
          <ExpenseDateFilter selectedYear={yearSelected} />
          {filteredData.map((data, key) => (
            <ExpenseItem expenseInfos={data} key={key} />
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default ExpenseList;
```

Comment: i have taken this code from your sandbox code just copy and paste this code in file and it worls